# Stop My Program and Another Program From Receiving REAL User Input

Tags: environment, restrict

I want to find a way to prevent my program (and a third party program being controlled by my program) from receiving any REAL user input.

We have purchased a third party program (a CAM program) to interface with our machines. And I have developed a program to use it to automate the use of that CAM program. Because the CAM program doesn't have its API exposed to my program, my program has to send key strokes to simulate the process of using the CAM program. This arrangement works AS LONG AS our user near the computer doesn't accidentally move the mouse or hit the keyboard; if this erroneous user input happens right at certain moment during the course of my program running, my program will lose track of where it is and cannot go on.  I want to find a way to fix this problem.

One way to fix this problem is to lock away the computer in a computer room. But this won't work because the user needs to use the CAM program to do their work (when my program is not running).

I have implemented a locking mechanism to prevent my program from being launched when the user is using the CAM program. But this doesn't prevent someone from accidentally moving the mouse or hitting a key when my program is running (and the user is not using the CAM program).

Another possible solution is to purchase two licenses of the CAM program, and assign the first license to a computer that will be locked away to run my program, and assign the second license for the user. But this costs quite a lot of money every year. And most of the time, that extra computer is just sitting there doing nothing.

I am wondering if there is a way for my program and the CAM program to run in a restricted environment in the same computer where they won't get any REAL user input, and all the user inputs that the CAM program will receive are fake ones that my program feeds to the CAM program.

By the way, the programs are running in Windows 10 environment.  My program is a Windows "console" program.  The CAM program looks like a typical Windows GUI program.

Please let me know what you think.  Thanks.

Jay C

Comment: Is this Windows?  That's an important aspect.

Comment: Yes, my program is a Windows "console" program.  It calls a Windows API (SendMessge()) to send keystrokes; I believe it still qualifies it as a console program.  The CAM program is a typical Windows application with GUI.  Because I don't have the source code of the CAM program, I cannot determine what type of Windows program it is.  Sorry for not being clear.  I will update my original posts to add this missing info.

Comment: The only options are not very good.  You can certainly disable the keyboard and mouse (using the devcon tool, for instance), as long as you have a way to re-enable them, either through a time delay or through an SSH login.  Or, since input is only sent to the process with focus, your app could send keystrokes and then change focus to some other app, like  a Notepad or something.

Comment: Thanks Tim for suggesting using devcon tool.  I will look into this along with PnPUtil.

Comment: Unfortunately this idea doesn't work.  Windows considers a keyboard as a critical system device, and doesn't allow us to disable the keyboard.  When I try to use PnPUtil to disable the keyboard, I get this error message "Cannot disable critical system device."  Actually I cannot disable the keyboard through Device Manager either - the "Disable Device" button in "Driver" screen for keyboard is disabled.  Therefore, there is no way to disable the keyboard through software.  I may try a hardware solution such as a gaming controller to switch between 2 sets of mouse and keyboard to avoid problem.

Comment: You may think it silly, but it's POSSIBLE that the best solution here is a physical one: put a box over the keyboard and mouse so they can't be moved while this operation is going on.  Or, plug them into a USB hub with on/off switches on the physical ports.  I use one of those daily.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  I was thinking along the line yesterday when I posted that message.  Currently we worked around the problem of someone mistakenly moving the mouse or hitting a key by using a cordless mouse and a cordless keyboard, and lift the mouse/keyboard off the table onto a shelf.  This works for that specific problem.  But this doesn't work for the next problem (that I will post below).

Comment: If someone is using the CAM program, I have a locking mechanism in place to prevent my program from launching.  But that lock only last for 1 hour.  After 1 hour, my program will start running regardless if someone is still using the CAM program or not.  This is to prevent my program from being locked out for too long and stopping all the pending works from being processed.  This can happen if someone launches the CAM program and walked away to a long meeting.  When he comes back, the locking mechanism has already unlocked.  But he is not aware of this, and he resumes working in CAM (cont...)

Comment: And then my program may start launching another copy of CAM program.  Because he is in the middle of working in his copy of CAM program, his use of mouse and keyboard will confuse my program, and will cause my program to hang.  Of course, I can extend the lock-out period from 1 hour to 2 hours.  But we don't want my program to be locked out for too long because we need the pending works to be processed.  At this point, I think we just have to educate our users to ask them to close the CAM program if they are not using it (this unlocks my program and resets the lockout period).